# Python list variable scope issues

Tags: python, function, variables, scope

I have the following code:

```
def myFunction(param, param):

    myList = ["",[],[],[]]

    #code to fill up myList
    for q,d in enumerate(detailCollection):
        #all the fun stuff here

    yield{
        "var1":myList[0],
        "var2":myList[1],
        #and so on
    }
```

The error I am getting is as follows:

```
NameError: name 'myList' is not defined
```

Coming from the lines in the `yield` statement

For privacy purposes I haven't included actual code, but this is identical situation of what is happening.  Why is it saying that `myList` is not defined when it is clearly in the same function scope, and how can I fix this problem?  I would rather not move the myList variable all the way out and call it a global variable, to keep the code clean and concise is there a way to do this without moving myList declaration/definition?

Comment: The error can't occur with the code you posted. You just have to post your actual code if you really want help.

Comment: nvm im just a complete idiot lol.  I completely overlooked a `_` in one of my variables in the yield.  So...  You are right :)  That's also part of the reason why I posted this question though because I felt really stupid haha

Answer (score 0):

So I didn't realize I had an extra `_` laying around in my `yield` statement.  No biggy :)  Problem solved.